# Pentaho CDE Change Column Order Dynamically for Table Element

Tags: datatable, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have a table component on my dashboard with value for past 12 month like this

[image]

My question is, for next month i need to manually change the order of columns 
(eg. first column will be OCT, second will be NOV etc.)

Is there any way i can change column order a JQuery data table according to the date of current month? If it is September right now, the last column will be Aug then back to 12 months. 
I was thinking of using something like [colReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/) funcion in JQuery in PRE EXECUTION.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do that in the post fetch of the table component : it's a function that take one parameter containing the resultset (explore it with the debugger) :

```
function(r) {

//rearrange the content of r according to your need. Beware to arrange both metadata and values!
     return(r); //This will return your modified resultset     
}
```